# Can multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() handle complex objects?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def load_cache(cache_name, resultq=None):

    with open(cache_name, 'rb') as input:
        cached_data = pickle.load(input)

    if not resultq:
        return cached_data
    else:
        try:
            resultq.put( (cache_name, cached_data) )    # getting error here
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()[1]

q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
info = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
procs = []
for i in zip(info, itertools.repeat(q)):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=load_cache, args=i)
    procs.append(p)
    p.daemon = False
    p.start()

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 240, in serve_client
         request = recv()
TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Not sure what this error means or how to go about fixing this. Any ideas?

NOTE:
if i make `cached_data` to some dummy value like `cached_data={}` it works fine.
`cached_data` is a dict with complex Python objects

if I remove `try/except` around `resultq.put()`,

```
File "main.py" line 20 in load_cache
    resultq.put((cache_name, cached_data))
File "<string>", line 2, in put
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 774, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
RemoteError:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell from your question what's happening, as there's the line

```
q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
```

referencing a `Queue`, but it's the only one. It's not clear from where your error is originating, as the line causing it doesn't seem to be in your listing.

---

`multiprocessing.Queue` shovels around bytes from place to place. Bytes are either few or many, but they are not simple or complex. In order to move objects through a `Queue`, they need to be serialized/deserialized (transformed to/from bytes form). 
`pickle` (and `cPickle`) are known to be problematic in terms of what the can serialize. You might have better luck with [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) (I've had positive experience with it). From the `dill` docs:

> Dill extends python’s ‘pickle’ module for serializing and de-serializing python objects to the majority of the built-in python types. ... Dill provides the user the same interface as the ‘pickle’ module, and also includes some additional features. In addition to pickling python objects, dill provides the ability to save the state of an interpreter session in a single command... Dill can be used to store python objects to a file, but the primary usage is to send python objects across the network as a byte stream.

Comment: how do you pickle between processes? with dill?

Comment: @ealeon Yes, I pickle everything with `dil`. When you pass arguments to the ctor of `Process`, it pickles with `pickle`, and so I even have the case where I `dill` stuff and then the results are `pickle`d. This is the only option that worked for me in many cases.

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  You might want to try `multiprocess`, which is a bare-bones fork of `multiprocessing` that bootstraps in `dill` as the serializer. https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Good job with dill. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
resultq.put((cache_name, pickle.dumps(cached_data)))
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

It cannot. As the documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

> A manager returned by `Manager()` will support types `list`, `dict`, `Namespace`, `Lock`, `RLock`, `Semaphore`, `BoundedSemaphore`, `Condition`, `Event`, `Queue`, `Value` and `Array`.